# Proof of intersection of two positive integer congruence classes

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am reviewing the foundation course I took in year 1 while a question caught my eyes：

Let A be the congruence class of 1 mod 3, and B the congruence class of -1 mod 4.
Prove that A∩B is a congruence class mod 12.

The answer is simple, 7 mod 12.
However, I wonder if I need to prove that when m,n happen to be coprime ( hcf(m,n)=1, i.e hcf(3,4)=1 here in particular ), there exist a,b ( a,b belong to integers ) in which am+bn=1 beforehand.

I am not certain about it since the proof of it seems a bit too much for a question phrased as above:
mZ+nZ=gZ for some g which belongs to natural numbers.
g must to be a common factor of m and n, since mZ and nZ are subgroups of gZ.
mZ+nZ (i.e gZ) is contained in every subgroup containing both mZ and nZ, hence,
gZ=mZ+nZ=hcf(m,n)Z

Therefore, 1-(-1)=2=2(4-3)=2*4-2*3,
2*4-1=7=2*3+1
lcm(3,4)=12

May I ask do I really need to write down the proof of existence of (a,b) such that am+bn=1 when hcf(m,n)=1in order to answer this question?

Also, I really struggle to explain how I come up with 12 here.

Thank you so much！

Regards,

Comment: I mean, it depends on whether you've covered Bezout's Theorem in your class already.

Comment: Thank you for the remind :D, I did learn the theorem and forgot its name. May I ask how can I deduce 12? I kind of lost myself here.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by come up with 12.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I wondered why it is modulo 12. I mean I have figured out the answer 7 mod 12. 7 thanks to your reminder, Bezout's Theorem, although by that time we have only figured the part am+bn=1 as a corollary. I still had no idea about the legit proof of modulo 12 which should be more comprehensive than a simple hcf(3,4)=12 in my answer. Thank you again :D

Comment: Brush up on the chinese remainder th.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you so much. I agree that using crt is the most effective way of solving this question. It is not covered in foundation course, unfortunately.(◔◡◔) I forgot crt completely XD

Comment: As you have had several answers, and some time to think about them, let me encourage you to "accept" one of them by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ if $\,x_0 \in A\cap B\,$ then $\,x \in A\cap B \!\iff\!  3,4\mid x\!-\!x_0\!\color{#c00}\iff\! 12\mid x\!-\!x_0\!\iff\! \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{x \in x_0\!+\!12\Bbb Z}$

**Remark** $ $ Generally for moduli $m,n\!:\ m,n\mid x\!-\!x_0\color{#c00}\iff {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid x\!-\! x_0.\,$ OP is the special case where $\,\gcd(m,n) = 1\  [\!\iff {\rm lcm}(m,n) = mn\:\!$].

This is equivalent to the *uniqueness* half or CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem (the other half = *existence* states that such an $\,x_0\,$  exsists). The view in terms of cosets becomes clearer if you study the ring-theoretic form of CRT, i.e.

$$ \gcd(m,n)=1\ \Rightarrow\ \Bbb Z/m \times \Bbb Z/n\, \cong\, \Bbb Z/mn\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I clearly see why 3 and 4 as devisors of x-x0, since we can rewrite x and x0 as x=3k+1, x0=3k0+1; x=4l-1, x0=4l0-1 where there exist two natural numbers k and k0. Thank you again (◔◡◔).

Answer (score 1):

If a number can be represented as both $3k+1$ and $4l-1$, then that number can also be represented as $12m+7$. This can be seen by a simple substitution:

Say $x=3k+1 = 4l-1$
$3k +2 = 4l$
$9k+6=12l$
$k+6 = 4(3l-2k) $
$k-2 = 4(3l-2k-2)$
$k = 2+4m$

Substituting $k$ back in $x$ gives
$$x=3k+1=3(4m+2)+1 = 12m+7$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The substitution is so impressive. Whilst I still don't quite get it why you would come up with the idea of multiplying by 3 here ( •̥́ ˍ •̀ू )

Comment: Ahh that was a bit tricky... Only multiplying by $3$ isolates $k$ by itself in $\mod 4$

Comment: At third step in the answer, multiplying by $3$ is not obvious at all yeah

Comment: We want to write $k$ as $r+4m$ so that when you plug $k$ back in $3k+1$, we will have used both the given info:  $x = 3k+1$ and $x=4l-1$

Comment: Thank you so much. I can see the intention of mutilplying 3 with the help from @Gerry Myerson 's answer.

Comment: yw:) Another not so clever way is to view the problem as solving the system of linear congruences: $x\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. First congruence gives $x=3k+1$. Plugging this in second congruence gives $3k+1\equiv -1 \pmod{4}$. solving this for $k$ and plugging back in $x$..

Answer (score 0):

Every congruence class modulo $3$ is the union of four congruence classes modulo $12$. Every congruence class modulo $4$ is the union of three congruence classes modulo $12$. So $A\cap B$ is the union of some number of congruence classes modulo $12$. To prove it's precisely one class, just try all $12$ classes and see that elements of $11$ of them don't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is very convincing :D